Always returning Null: Using Select Statement in creating a function in oracle SQL developer
FOR ANYONE HAVING THE SAME PROBLEM, I WAS ABLE TO SOLVE THIS BY REMOVING '_' IN MY VARCHAR2 PARAMETER NAME
I need help in this, I've been stuck in here for too long. I have tried multiple things already. Would appreciate any troubleshoot.
I have an existing table where the rows are the types of KPIs, and the rows are the targets on multiple target levels.



KPI
target_50
target_100
target_150




KPI A
5
10
20


KPI B
10
30
50



Now, I am creating a function that requires two parameters: the raw score and the KPI type.
For example:
KPI(6,'KPI A') would return 50%
KPI(10,'KPI 1') would return 100%
KPI(9,'KPI B') would return 0%
KPI(100,'KPI B') would return 150%
This is my script:
create or replace FUNCTION KPI(RAW_SCORE in NUMBER, KPI_TYPE in VARCHAR2)

RETURN NUMBER AS

ACTUAL_SCORE NUMBER;

BEGIN

    select case when RAW_SCORE >= target_150 then 1.50
                when RAW_SCORE >= target_100 then 1.00
                when RAW_SCORE >= target_50 then 0.50
            else 0
            end into ACTUAL_SCORE
    from TARGETS_TABLE
    where TARGETS_TABLE.KPI = KPI_TYPE;
RETURN ACTUAL_SCORE;

However, this always returns NULL. I have tried running the same SELECT statement and manual input the raw_score and kpi_type. It returns the expected value. But the function always returns null whatever I input.
Here is the script for the targets table:
  CREATE TABLE "TARGETS_TABLE" 
   (    "KPI" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),  
    "TARGET_50" NUMBER(38,14), 
    "TARGET_100" NUMBER(38,14), 
    "TARGET_150" NUMBER(38,17)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA" ;

I would appreciate any insights and troubleshooting that I could try. Thank you so much.
I tried creating a user-defined function with a SELECT statement inside where the two input parameters will be used. I'm expecting a value to be returned, but it is always null.

Does the select statement, if executed outside of the function, give any value?

Your table is missing a target_125 column and the function is missing an END; statement - assuming those two are typos then your function works fiddle. If you are getting NULL values then please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for the relevant tables so that we can replicate the problem - because, at the moment, we cannot replicate the issue.

As a good practice, prefix your function parameters (eg p_raw_score). It makes your code more readable and it prevents unwanted results if column names match parameter names.

@LasseV.Karlsen yes it does.

@MT0 I have added the statements there. Also, the missing target_125 and missing End; statement are just typos. Thanks, I've tried it on your link, it worked just as I expected. But can't make it work on my database end. :(

@KoenLostrie, thank you, this makes sense.

@anon_stat_123 What is the actual CREATE TABLE statement used for TARGETS_TABLE (and not the one you've copied from my fiddle)? The answer below tells you why you are getting NULL values and if you are always getting NULL then my guess is that the KPI_TYPE column is something like CHAR(10) and not VARCHAR2(10) (but that is also covered in the answer below).

@MT0, oh okay. I have edited my question above. Apparently, KPI column from the targets table is already in VARCHAR2, which is similar with the parameter KPI_TYPE.

@anon_stat_123 Then you need to check the data. If the table has kpi a and you are searching for KPI A then it won't match. Similar for KPI A    (with trailing spaces) and KPI A.

@MT0, i see i see. Thanks, I've followed your tip and made TARGETS_TABLE.KPI = KPI_TYPE --> upper(trim(TARGETS_TABLE.KPI)) = upper(trim(KPI_TYPE)). Still returning null.

What is the output of calling the function from PL/SQL using DECLARE v_kpi NUMBER; BEGIN v_kpi := KPI(100, 'KPI A'); END; (assuming that KPI A is a valid lookup value)?

Also, are you sure that you are: connecting to the correct database; connecting as the correct user; calling the correct function; calling the function belonging to the correct user; using the correct TARGETS_TABLE table owned by the correct user; etc.? Sorry, but sometimes its the simple things like you're querying the wrong thing. If you do SELECT owner, object_name, object_type, status FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE  object_name IN ('KPI', 'TARGETS_TABLE'); does it show only one KPI function and one table and are they both valid?

@MT0, yes, I really understand that sometimes it's these minute things that mess us up -- Thank you. However, yeah, I'm sure these are all correct. I was able to create a similar function, only that it only requires one parameter -- the raw_score. I just set the kpi_type as constant by doing  WHERE TARGETS_TABLE.KPI = 'KPI B'. That function works properly as expected. The problem, somehow, arises when I require two parameters - the raw_score and kpi_type.

If you look at fiddle, can you do something similar and compare the output when you DUMP() the function argument's value and the value in the table? If they don't match then you can look at what extra characters are in either the argument or the table. If using DUMP() doesn't show the difference between the two and nothing else suggested works then I'm running out of ideas why the function would not work.

@MT0, tried everything you have suggested, however function still doesn't work. almost gave up, but decided to remove the '_' in KPI_TYPE (parameter name), and the function finally worked. I don't know why KPI_TYPE doesn't work, but that was only the problem from the very start. Thank you man for the troubleshooting methods you've suggested, really helped me cross-out other possible issues in my function script.

The KPI_TYPE value that you are passing to the function does not exist in the TARGETS_TABLE table and the function is raising a NO DATA FOUND exception when it tries to use SELECT ... INTO ... and the select matches zero rows.
The SQL query is receiving the NO DATA FOUND exception and understands that to mean that the returned value should be NULL and silently consumes the exception and substitutes NULL in its place.
For example, if you have the data:
CREATE TABLE targets_table (KPI, target_50, target_100, target_125, target_150) AS
SELECT 'KPI A',  5, 10, 15, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KPI B', 10, 30, 40, 50 FROM DUAL;

Then:
SELECT KPI(100, 'KPI C') FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



KPI(100,'KPIC')




null



But performing the same function call in PL/SQL (rather than in SQL):
DECLARE
  v_kpi NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_kpi := KPI(100, 'KPI C');
END;
/

Shows the underlying exception:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_PTZQEOEAQSCSHGUJATEJ.KPI", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 4


The solution is to pass a KPI_TYPE value to the function that actually exists in the table.

However, if you have create the table using the CHAR data-type for the KPI columns:
CREATE TABLE targets_table (
  KPI        CHAR(10),
  target_50  NUMBER,
  target_100 NUMBER,
  target_125 NUMBER,
  target_150 NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO targets_table (KPI, target_50, target_100, target_125, target_150)
SELECT 'KPI A',  5, 10, 15, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KPI B', 10, 30, 40, 50 FROM DUAL;

Then:
SELECT KPI(100, 'KPI B') FROM DUAL;

Will output:



KPI(100,'KPIB')




null



But:
SELECT KPI(100, 'KPI B     ') FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



KPI(100,'KPIB')




1.5



Because you have padded the KPI to the correct column length.
In this case, the best solution would be to convert the KPI column from CHAR(10) to VARCHAR2(10) as you are using variable-length, rather than fixed-length, strings. If you cannot do that then set the KPI_TYPE argument to have the same type as the column (which will implicitly pad shorter strings to the correct length) - however, using a VARCHAR2 column should be preferred (although you can use both):
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KPI(
  RAW_SCORE IN TARGETS_TABLE.TARGET_50%TYPE,
  KPI_TYPE  IN TARGETS_TABLE.KPI%TYPE
)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  ACTUAL_SCORE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select case when RAW_SCORE >= target_150 then 1.50
              when RAW_SCORE >= target_125 then 1.25
              when RAW_SCORE >= target_100 then 1.00
              when RAW_SCORE >= target_50 then 0.50
         else 0
         end
  into   ACTUAL_SCORE
  from   TARGETS_TABLE
  where  TARGETS_TABLE.KPI = KPI_TYPE;

  RETURN ACTUAL_SCORE;
END;
/


Alternatively, if you want exactly the same functionality in a query (without the function - even to replicating the behaviour for NO DATA FOUND and TOO MANY ROWS exceptions if KPI_TYPE matches zero or multiple rows, respectively) then you can use a correlated sub-query:
-- sample test data
WITH data (raw_score, kpi_type) AS (
  SELECT 10, 'KPI A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'KPI B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'KPI C' FROM DUAL
)
-- query starts here
SELECT raw_score,
       kpi_type,
       (
         select case
                when d.RAW_SCORE >= t.target_150 then 1.50
                when d.RAW_SCORE >= t.target_125 then 1.25
                when d.RAW_SCORE >= t.target_100 then 1.00
                when d.RAW_SCORE >= t.target_50  then 0.50
                else 0
                end
         from   TARGETS_TABLE t
         where  t.KPI = d.KPI_TYPE
       ) AS kpi
FROM   data d

fiddle

Maybe you don't need the function at all. Assuming that there are some data about testing the scores and that the function is intended to be called as a part of some selection list maybe you could consider doing it without the function...
WITH   --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    targets_table (KPI, TARGET_50, TARGET_100, TARGET_150) AS
        ( Select 'KPI A',  5, 10, 20 From Dual UNion All
          Select 'KPI B', 10, 30, 50 From Dual
        ),

... below is a cte (test_scores) containing ROW_SCOREs and KPI_TYPEs of possible interest. If you plan to call the function (passing parameters to it) using sql - consider the code below this cte as a possible solution...
--  dummy data as a sample
    test_scores (ID, RAW_SCORE, KPI_TYPE) AS
        ( Select 1,   6, 'KPI A' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2,  10, 'KPI 1' From Dual Union All 
          Select 3,  10, 'KPI A' From Dual Union All 
          Select 4,   9, 'KPI B' From Dual Union All
          Select 5, 100, 'KPI B' From Dual
        )

... the code to get the scores (either 1 or more)
--      S Q L :
Select    ts.ID, ts.RAW_SCORE, ts.KPI_TYPE,
          Case When tt.KPI Is Null Then Null
               When ts.RAW_SCORE >= TARGET_150 Then 1.50
               When ts.RAW_SCORE >= TARGET_100 Then 1.00
               When ts.RAW_SCORE >= TARGET_50  Then 0.50
          Else 0
          End "ACTUAL_SCORE",
          Case When tt.KPI Is Null Then 'No such KPI_TYPE in targets_table' End "NOTE"
From      test_scores ts  
Left Join targets_table tt ON(tt.KPI = ts.KPI_TYPE)
--Where tt.KPI = 'some KPI'    <<<---- when you need to filter the resultset
Order By  ts.ID

/*      R e s u l t :
ID  RAW_SCORE  KPI_TYPE  ACTUAL_SCORE  NOTE
--  ---------  --------  ------------  -----------------------------------
 1          6  KPI A              0.5   
 2         10  KPI 1                   No such KPI_TYPE in targets_table
 3         10  KPI A                1   
 4          9  KPI B                0   
 5        100  KPI B              1.5                                       */

